# How come I can connect to my RDS endpoint via MySQL GUI but not via my Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, debugging, amazon-rds

I can successfully connect to my RDS endpoint via a MySQL GUI but upon trying to connect in my Laravel project (by logging in with a user, for example) I get an error that says

`[object] (PDOException(code: 0): PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for myRdsEndpoint.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com failed: Name or service not known at *my/Project/Path*`

I've verified that:

- The RDS endpoint in `.env` file on the EC2 instance, along with the login information, is correct
- The RDS login information in the database.php file is correct

I've tried:

- Rebooting the RDS instance
- Modifying the `boot()` method in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` to:

```
if($this->app->environment('production')) {
     $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS','on');
}
```

I've exhausted all options but nothing works.  I've hit a wall. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Make sure your EC2 instance has a security group that is able to connect to the RDS instance. We have a security group with one rule: to allow all traffic to anyone in that security group and then we attach that to all AWS resources we want to have accessible from each other

Comment: @apokryfos I have that already.  Check the screenshot in my original post. does it look good?

Comment: Not sure. That's a bit excessive because it's open for everyone. Try adding another rule but put the security group id as the source, though it should work as it is.

Comment: @apokryfos yeah it's a bit excessive for sure, I just want to able to connect in my Lsravel project.  If I'm able to connect via a MySQL GUI, how come I can't connect in Laravel project?  That's what I'm stumped about.

Comment: Can you connect via your Laravel project locally ( not on EC2 ) or does that not work either?

Comment: @apokryfos yeah I can connect locally with no issues.  I actually just verified that.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to networking issue.
May you check:

1. Whether you can resolve the RDS endpoint on your EC2 instance (like via SSH , EC2 Instance Connect, Systems Manager etc.)

   ```bash
   nslookup myRdsEndpoint.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
   ```
2. Is there any security group for the RDS instance that permits inbound access from the EC2 instance's public IP address?